# Laravel getting collection ordered by relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 2 tables, one is magazine and the other is issues. I have set up their relationship like this:

Magazine model:

```
 public function issues()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Issue')->orderBy('date', 'desc');
 }
```

Issue model:

```
public function magazine()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Magazine');
}
```

I have a query where I get magazines ordered by a column and then in foreach loop I am getting the first issue of each magazine and storing it in array:

```
    $magazines = Magazine::with('issues')->orderBy('order')->get();

    foreach ($magazines as $magazine)
    {
        $issues[] = $magazine->issues()->first();
        $images[] = $magazine->issues()->first()->image;
    }
```

But, I would like to make a collection instead of an array. I am not sure how can I do that kind of query or is there a way to somehow store values to a collection in a foreach loop?

Comment: How many rows already available in `magazine` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

You can turn an array into a collection by doing the following.

```
$issuesCollection = collect($issues);
$imagesCollection = collect($images);
```

You could also initialize an empty collection and then use the `push()` method to append items to it. Check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map) function:

```
$magazines = Magazine::with('issues')->orderBy('order')->get();

$firstIssues = $magazines->map(function($magazine) {
   return $magazine->issues->first();
});

$images = $firstIssues->map(function($issue) {
    return $issue->image;
});
```

> The map method iterates through the collection and passes each value
>   to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and
>   return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items

Comment: You should change `$magazine->issues()->first();` to `$magazine->issues->first();`. The issues are already eager loaded with the first query, yet you're using another query for each magazine to reload the first issue in the map callback. This is redundant and inefficient.

Comment: Your second map is also wrong. You would need to map the `$firstIssues` collection, not the `$magazines` collection to get the image.